# What can SCVs Repair?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-terran, starcraft-protoss

What units and structures in Starcraft can be repaired? Can allied units from other races be repaired?

Comment: Could you extend that question to structures like Protoss and Zerg buildings.

Comment: Could you also extend the scope of the question to cover neutral buildings?

Comment: Actually, do you mind if I change the question to "What can SCV's repair?" Then include in the details a number of questions about ambiguous rules like allied mechanical Toss units, Toss buildings, and neutral buildings. A high quality answer will include the information you're currently asking for and additional related information.

Comment: I wouldn't mind that at all :)

Comment: What do you mean by neutral buildings?

Comment: Neutral buildings like the lowered supply depot at the bottom of ramps on some maps (or maybe this is just a BW thing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found this which answers all questions!

> SCVs can repair Terran buildings or mechanical units (including other SCVs) under attack which is a key part of defending early game pushes.

Basically put: SCVs can repair any **Terran** structures or **any** mechanical units. "any" isn't in the original quote but I want to put emphasis on the fact it does not narrow down mechanical units to a specific race.

Of course they can only ever repair allied units. As a side note, Zerg does not have any mechanical units and if he Neural Parasite'd one the unit would still be Terran or Protoss.

**[Source](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/SCV)**

Comment: Can you cite a source, or better yet, post screenshots, or better yet, post a video?

Comment: @BBz: Why should he post a source? I mean if he tried it and it works that is proof enough.

Comment: @ayckoster I believe it'd improve the quality of the answer

Comment: Why the 2 downvotes? Its the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

SCVs can repair any mechanical units, Protoss or Terran or Zerg(if they manage to build any, eg via NPing a worker) of any of their allies. They can only heal health, and not shields, however.